# did SubethaSmtp store emails somewhere?

Tags: smtp, imap

I use the [SubethaSmtp](https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp) library as an email server and so far I have been able to run this server and test it by sending an email. Email information is printed in the output. As far as I know, smtp protocol is used to send emails. While IMAP protocol is used to receive emails. My question is, did SubethaSmtp store emails somewhere (such as a database or file)? In general, do I need a server other than SubethaSmtp server to receive emails? What will be the relationship between these two protocols?

My code is written in the following two Java classes:

BasicSMTPServer class:

```java
package com.sojoodi;

import org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer;


public class BasicSMTPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMessageHandlerFactory myFactory = new MyMessageHandlerFactory();
        SMTPServer smtpServer = new SMTPServer(myFactory);

        smtpServer.setPort(25000);

        smtpServer.start();

        System.out.println("smtpServer = " + smtpServer);
        System.out.println("HostName = " + smtpServer.getHostName());
    }
}
```

and MyMessageHandlerFactory class:

```java
package com.sojoodi;

import org.subethamail.smtp.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyMessageHandlerFactory implements MessageHandlerFactory {
    public MessageHandler create(MessageContext ctx) {
        return new Handler(ctx);
    }

    class Handler implements MessageHandler {
        MessageContext ctx;

        public Handler(MessageContext ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void from(String from) throws RejectException {
            System.out.println("FROM:"+from);
        }

        public void recipient(String recipient) throws RejectException {
            System.out.println("RECIPIENT:"+recipient);
        }

        public void data(InputStream data) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("MAIL DATA");
            System.out.println("= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =");
            System.out.println(this.convertStreamToString(data));
            System.out.println("= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =");
        }

        public void done() {
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }

        public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's three questions, not one, and none of then sound concrete enough to answer without access to your code. Please refine the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the [Receive emails with SubEtha SMTP and Spring Boot](https://redamessoudi.com/receive-emails-with-subetha-springboot/) post and for you question about storing you can check the issues section in the related code repository as there is an [issue](https://github.com/redamessoudi/subethasmtp-springboot/issues/1) same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You should create instance of SMTPServer and pass your factory to it, like:

```
SMTPServer smtp = SMTPServer
    .port(config.getPort())
    .hostName(config.getHostname())
    .messageHandlerFactory(new MyMessageHandlerFactory())
    .build();

smtp.start();
```